# Is reinstall an Android app same as Upgrading

Tags: android, upgrade

I have a doubt in upgrading android app.
I made changes to code and changed the version.Then tried to install in device.So i got a prompt to "un install the previous app and reinstall". But actually i need to check how the upgrade works.I found in google that without UN-installing  previous app ,new app can be installed by performing reinstall.

I tried in command line

```
adb install -r app_name.apk
```

But I didn’t find anywhere that this command is for upgrading.Everywhere it is mentioning as reinstall only.I am really doubted whether both are same.That is **whether Reinstall is same as upgrading android app.**
Can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience,
Whenever I click to update a App in android, Its check/compares the version and If its having updated version available, It uninstalls the previous version and install new one.

But the difference is, when it updates, the app settings, user preferences etc.  is maintained with new version also.

Please share, If you having a different experience on this.

Comment: the term "uninstall" is wrong there. There is a difference between update (which also means "reinstall") and uninstall. So I would be careful to say "uninstall" when describing the update process.

Comment: Thanks dear. Can you elaborate it more. I mean what actually happens in "reinstall".

Comment: Basically the app will be replaced but the files for the database and the shared preferences are kept. Nothing more...

Comment: Ok buddy, I also mentioned the same thing, But couldn't convey properly. you made it clear now. thanks again.